# How can I align button in Center or right using IONIC framework?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

[image]

I want the login and register button in **right**,and Search button in **Center**, I searched alot but didn't get any solution.

And also how can I align text area in a proper position.

Here is my html code:

```
<body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane  style = "background-color:#4992E2;">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader" style = " margin-top: -35px; background-color:#F9F9F9;">
        <h1 class="title" style = "color:black;">NetHealth Appointment Booking</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content >
          <div class = "row center">
               <div class="col">
                    <button class="button button-small  button-light" >
                      Login!
                    </button>
                     <button class="button button-small  button-light">
                      Register Here!
                    </button>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item-input-inset">
            <h4>Date</h4> 

          <label class="item-input-wrapper">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Text Area">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="item-input-inset">
            <h4>Suburb</h4>

          <label class="item-input-wrapper">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Text Area">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="item-input-inset">
            <h4>Clinic</h4>
          <label class="item-input-wrapper">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Text Area">
          </label>
        </div>
        <button class=" center button button-small  button-light">
          Search
        </button>

        </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
```

I know in the **bootstrap**, but I am new to ionic, please tell me how can I do this.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Css is going to work in same manner i assume.

You can center the content with something like this :

```
.center{
     text-align:center;
}
```

**Update**

To adjust the width in proper manner, modify your DOM as below :

```
<div class="item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper"> Date
        <input type="text" placeholder="Text Area" />
    </label>
</div>
<div class="item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper"> Suburb
        <input type="text" placeholder="Text Area" />
    </label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
label {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100%;
    font-weight:bold;
}

input{
    float:right; /* shift to right for alignment*/
    width:80% /* set a width, you can use max-width to limit this as well*/
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bf684mbm/2/)

**final update**

If you don't plan to modify existing HTML (*one in your question originally*), below css would make me your best friend!! :)

```
html, body, .con {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.item-input-inset {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.item-input-inset > h4 {
    float:left;
    margin-top:0;/* important alignment */
    width:15%;
}
.item-input-wrapper {
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:85%;
}
input {
    width:100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bf684mbm/4/)

Comment: `text-align` aligns the control as well? The OP wants to align the button in the page.

Comment: thanks, it is working, and please tell me about text area width, how can I fix with same width, now it is depend upon the text in front of text area.

Comment: @PreetySapra : you have used `label` in incorrect manner, please check the update!

Comment: after update the code that you suggest, not working the text "Date" go inside the text-area.

Comment: @PreetySapra : looks fine in the fiddle....have you applied the same HTML as in my solution?

Comment: yes I used same code that you suggest....I will post again the image what I am getting after use your code...

Comment: @PreetySapra : ok...meanwhile, i'll try to make amends on your original HTML! :)

Comment: yup..i saw the image, reason it is happening is because in your original CSS somewhere, `label` has `background` set as white may be, so it appears that all has merged into one...if you do `input{border:1px solid green}`, it'll show that they are 2 different elements actually... :)

Comment: you added `border` to the `input`? does it shows covering the "Date" inside `textarea`?

Comment: nothing happen that image I have sent same is coming, and if I try my code in Fiddle then it work fine...I don't know why it is not working on browser....

Comment: @PreetySapra : no worries mate, i just updated the CSS for your original HTML...check if it helps! :)

Comment: I'm sorry. I've the same problem, I want to center a button, but I don't understand how I can do it using this solution.. can you explain to me please? I'll vote your question

Comment: @AlfonsoSilvestri : can you give me your basic layout on https://jsfiddle.net/ ??

Answer (score 90):

You should put the button inside a div, and in the div you should be able to use the classes:
 **text-left**, **text-center** and **text-right**.

for example:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col text-center">
      <button class="button button-small button-light">Search</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

And about the "textarea" position:

```
<div class="list">
<label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Date</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Text Area">
</label>
```

Demo using your code:
http://codepen.io/douglask/pen/zxXvYY

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted one since it uses Ionic classes instead of extra vanilla CSS (which is a totally acceptable solution, but the OP asked for Ionic! :) ).

Comment: Correct syntax for RC3 should be: `<ion-row>
  <ion-col text-center>
    <button></button>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>`

Answer (score 20):

To use center alignment in ionic app code itself, you can use the following code:

```
<ion-row center>  
 <ion-col text-center>   
  <button ion-button>Search</button>  
 </ion-col> 
</ion-row>
```

To use right alignment in ionic app code itself, you can use the following code:

```
<ion-row right>  
 <ion-col text-right>   
  <button ion-button>Search</button>  
 </ion-col> 
</ion-row>
```

Answer (score 7):

Ultimately, we are trying to get to this.

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <button ion-button>Login</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

And if we want to align a checkbox to the right, we can use item-end.

```
<ion-checkbox checked="true" item-end></ion-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Ionic way.  Using this ion-buttons tag, and the right keyword puts all the buttons in this group to the right.  I made some custom toggle buttons that i wanted on one line, but the group to be right justified.

```html
<ion-buttons right>
<button ....>1</button>
<button ....>2</button>
<button ....>3</button>
</ion-buttons>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found the esiest soltuion just wrap the button with div and put  text-center align-items-center in it like this  :

```
<div text-center align-items-center>
<buttonion-button block class="button-design " text-center>Sign In </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

`center` tag aligns the buttons within it as expected:

```
<ion-footer>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <center>
            <button royal>
                Contacts
                <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <button secondary>
                Receive
                <ion-icon name="arrow-round-back"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <button danger>
                Wallet
                <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <button secondary>
                Send
                <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <button danger>
                Transactions
                <ion-icon name="archive"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <button danger>
                About
                <ion-icon name="information-circle"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </center>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: -1, because OP asked for Ionic Framework, which uses HTML5, and `<center>` is not supported in HTML5: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp